# Entity framework Attach error after a query

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

Why is the attach of an entity throwing an exception if it is right after a query on the same db entity.

> Attaching an entity of type 'Article' failed because another entity of
>   the same type already has the same primary key value. This can happen
>   when using the 'Attach' method or setting the state of an entity to
>   'Unchanged' or 'Modified' if any entities in the graph have
>   conflicting key values. This may be because some entities are new and
>   have not yet received database-generated key values. In this case use
>   the 'Add' method or the 'Added' entity state to track the graph and
>   then set the state of non-new entities to 'Unchanged' or 'Modified'
>   as appropriate.

Removing the query before the attach statement makes it work as expected.

My controller:

```
public JsonResult Update(Article entity)
{
    JsonResult jRes = new JsonResult();
    ArticleDA repo = new ArticleDA();
    jRes.Data = repo.Update(entity);
    return jRes;
}
```

My Model

```
public Result Update(Article entity)
{
    Result result = new Result();
    using (Entities entities = new Entities())
    {
        try
        {
            var article = entities.Article.Where(x => x.id == entity.id).FirstOrDefault();
            entities.Article.Attach(entity);
            entities.Entry(entity).State = EntityState.Modified;

            entities.SaveChanges();
            result.OK = true;
        }
        catch (Exception err)
        {
            result.OK = false;
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

I know the query before the attach statement doesn't make sense, but I was just wondering why querying the db before the attach throws an exception.

Is it because querying the db for an entity with that id makes it available to the EntityFramework?

Please can you explain why this happens?

Comment: You can check `article`, if exist remove localy it using `entities.Entry(article ).State = EntityState.Detached;`

Comment: With the query you are pulling a `Article` with same Id as your parameter entity into the context. If you then try to add your parameter, it will fail as the Id is already present.

Comment: Ha that makes sense @Mats391 thanks ;-)

Answer (score 1):

If you only want to pass over the error, try `var article = entities.Article.AsNoTracking().Where(x => x.id == entity.id).FirstOrDefault();`

If you want to know why this is happening, wait for my complete answer